# Polars: smart way to avoid "window expression not allowed in aggregation"

Tags: python, python-polars

I have the following code which works.

```
import numpy as np 
import polars as pl 

data = {
    "date": ["2021-01-01", "2021-01-02", "2021-01-03", "2021-01-04", "2021-01-05", "2021-01-06", "2021-01-07", "2021-01-08", "2021-01-09", "2021-01-10", "2021-01-11", "2021-01-12", "2021-01-13", "2021-01-14", "2021-01-15", "2021-01-16", "2021-01-17", "2021-01-18", "2021-01-19", "2021-01-20"],
    "close": np.random.randint(100, 110, 10).tolist() + np.random.randint(200, 210, 10).tolist(),
    "company": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"] 
}
df = pl.DataFrame(data).with_columns(date = pl.col("date").cast(pl.Date))

# Calculate Returns
R = pl.col("close").pct_change()

# Calculate Gains and Losses
G = pl.when(R > 0).then(R).otherwise(0).alias("gain")
L = pl.when(R < 0).then(R).otherwise(0).alias("loss")

# Calculate Moving Averages for Gains and Losses
window = 3
MA_G = G.rolling_mean(window).alias("MA_gain")
MA_L = L.rolling_mean(window).alias("MA_loss")

# Calculate Relative Strength Index based on Moving Averages
RSI = (100 - (100 / (1 + MA_G / MA_L))).alias("RSI")

df = df.with_columns(R, G, L, MA_G, MA_L, RSI)

df.head()
```

I like the ability to compose different steps using `polars`, because it keeps my code readable and easy to maintain (as opposed to method chaining). Note that ultimately calculations are more complex.

However, now I want to calculate the above column but grouped by "company". I tried adding `.over("company")` where relevant. However, this doesn't work.

```
# Calculate Returns
R = pl.col("close").pct_change().over("company")

# Calculate Gains and Losses
G = pl.when(R > 0).then(R).otherwise(0).alias("gain")
L = pl.when(R < 0).then(R).otherwise(0).alias("loss")

# Calculate Moving Averages for Gains and Losses
window = 3
MA_G = G.rolling_mean(window).alias("MA_gain").over("company")
MA_L = L.rolling_mean(window).alias("MA_loss").over("company")

# Calculate Relative Strength Index based on Moving Averages
RSI = (100 - (100 / (1 + MA_G / MA_L))).over("company").alias("RSI")

df = df.with_columns(R, G, L, MA_G, MA_L, RSI)

df.head()
```

**Questions**

1.) What is the best way to fix this `"window expression not allowed in aggregation"` error while keeping the above code approach?

2.) Related question: why is window expression not allowed in aggregation in the first place. What is the problem with this from a technical perspective? Can someone explain to me in laymans terms?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`over()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.over.html) applies to the whole expression, so your code actually works if you remove `over` on MA_G / MA_L columns:

```py
# Calculate Returns
R = pl.col("close").pct_change().over("company")

# Calculate Gains and Losses
G = pl.when(R > 0).then(R).otherwise(0).alias("gain")
L = pl.when(R < 0).then(R).otherwise(0).alias("loss")

# Calculate Moving Averages for Gains and Losses
window = 3
MA_G = G.rolling_mean(window).alias("MA_gain")
MA_L = L.rolling_mean(window).alias("MA_loss")

# Calculate Relative Strength Index based on Moving Averages
RSI = (100 - (100 / (1 + MA_G / MA_L))).over("company").alias("RSI")

df = df.with_columns(R, G, L, MA_G, MA_L, RSI)

df.head()

────────────┬───────────┬─────────┬──────────┬───────────┬──────────┬───────────┬────────────┐
│ date       ┆ close     ┆ company ┆ gain     ┆ loss      ┆ MA_gain  ┆ MA_loss   ┆ RSI        │
│ ---        ┆ ---       ┆ ---     ┆ ---      ┆ ---       ┆ ---      ┆ ---       ┆ ---        │
│ date       ┆ f64       ┆ str     ┆ f64      ┆ f64       ┆ f64      ┆ f64       ┆ f64        │
╞════════════╪═══════════╪═════════╪══════════╪═══════════╪══════════╪═══════════╪════════════╡
│ 2021-01-01 ┆ null      ┆ A       ┆ 0.0      ┆ 0.0       ┆ null     ┆ null      ┆ null       │
│ 2021-01-02 ┆ -0.055046 ┆ A       ┆ 0.0      ┆ -0.055046 ┆ null     ┆ null      ┆ null       │
│ 2021-01-03 ┆ 0.019417  ┆ A       ┆ 0.019417 ┆ 0.0       ┆ 0.006472 ┆ -0.018349 ┆ -54.5      │
│ 2021-01-04 ┆ -0.038095 ┆ A       ┆ 0.0      ┆ -0.038095 ┆ 0.006472 ┆ -0.031047 ┆ -26.338197 │
│ 2021-01-05 ┆ 0.059406  ┆ A       ┆ 0.059406 ┆ 0.0       ┆ 0.026274 ┆ -0.012698 ┆ 193.535335 │
└────────────┴───────────┴─────────┴──────────┴───────────┴──────────┴───────────┴────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! So basically in my code I implicitly did `over(...).over(...)` which was the problem then?

Comment: So basically I could do `df = df.with_columns([e.over("company") for e in [R, G, L, MA_G, MA_L, RSI]])` using my first approach. This is awesome!

Comment: @FredMaster That would indeed work. I think the code above would not run as you still have a nested `over` for *R*. This can be avoided by using `with_columns` first to evaluate expression *R* and then reference the *close* column directly.